# Numeric|max Throws Bad Method Call Exception

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-formrequest

I'm recieving the following error from the from request class in Laravel.

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateNumeric|max does not exist.
in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:1532
```

This is my validation rule:

```
['required', 'integer', 'numeric|max:90', new UniqueWhenNew]
```

The value I passed is 70.

Apperantly, this is a strange situation because I didn't find anything similar on Google.

I hope someone knows what is the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use all rules in string or array.

```
$rules = ['required', 'integer', 'numeric', 'max:90', new UniqueWhenNew]
```